# remove an element from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I need help to remove an element from a linked list, by user prompt. Any help is appreciated. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public void removeList(LinkedList someList)
{

    System.out.println(someList);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a String to Delete:");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++)
    {
    if(s.equals(someList))
    {
    someList.remove(s);
    System.out.println(someList.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: s.equals(someList.get(i)) maybe  ?

Comment: what is `if(s.equals(someList))` supposed to do?

Comment: And don't use `System.out.println(someList.get(i));` after you just deleted that entry. Use `break;` instead to stop the loop.

Comment: do you really have to roll your own [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method like that?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use loop here. You can directly call remove method.

Try below

```
public void removeList(LinkedList someList) {

    System.out.println(someList);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a String to Delete:");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    someList.remove(s);
    System.out.println(someList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will avoid for loop

```
public void removeList(LinkedList someList)
{      
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a String to Delete:");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    if (someList.contains(s))
        someList.remove(s);
    System.out.println(someList);     
}
```

Comment: No need for the `contains` check. [`remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) will only succeed if the list contains the item.